# what's wrong with this jQuery method?

Tags: jquery

I have this method:

```
function replaceRightClickIcefacesMethod() {
    var oldName = jQuery(".singlePaneOfGlassBlock").attr("oncontextmenu");
    oldName = oldName.replace('Ice.Menu.contextMenuPopup', 'contextMenuPopupUpdated');

    jQuery(".singlePaneOfGlassBlock").attr("oncontextmenu", oldName);
}
```

I do not understand why Firebug reports:

> ```
> oldName.replace is not a function
> ```

Do you see any issue? For me it's just weird...

**UPDATE**: Just notice that oldName returns a function, if I do alert(oldName):

```
function oncontextmenu(event) {
Ice.Menu.contextMenuPopup(event, "j_id88:sectionContextMenu_sub", "j_id88:j_id111:0:j_id123:0:j_id124");
return false;
```

}

Comment: What does oldName contain after init?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before jQuery 1.6, `jQuery(".singlePaneOfGlassBlock").attr("oncontextmenu")` returns a function as it returns the *property* of the DOM element and not the *attribute* ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/LcKfZ/)).

This is fixed in jQuery 1.6 ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/LcKfZ/1/)).

If you cannot use jQuery 1.6, you have to call [**`getAttribute`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute) on the DOM element:

```
var oldName = jQuery(".singlePaneOfGlassBlock")[0].getAttribute('onclick');
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if `oldName` is `null`...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe remove assignation in third line? Replace may return number of entries replaced.

```
function replaceRightClickIcefacesMethod(){
  var oldName = jQuery(".singlePaneOfGlassBlock").attr("oncontextmenu");
  oldName.replace('Ice.Menu.contextMenuPopup','contextMenuPopupUpdated');

  jQuery(".singlePaneOfGlassBlock").attr("oncontextmenu",oldName);

}
```

Comment: `replace` is not in-place. It returns a new string. But anyway, the error is *oldName.replace is not a function* which means the `replace` does not exist in the first place.